# I'm trying to figure out the Big O Time Complexity of this equation

Tags: java, big-o

The code refers to a basic Tree data structure (Node).

```
public int countLeaf2(Node <T> tree) {
    if (tree.children.isEmpty() != true) {
        for (int i=0; i<tree.children.size(); i++) {
            countLeaf2(tree.children.get(i));
        }
    }
    if (tree.children.size() == 2) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Notes**

- the code in question seems to not do what it supposed to do (that is to count the total nodes in a tree node), and instead it only counts the first non-empty child nodes.
- the method would also not compile as the local variable `count` wasn't declared anywhere **within the method**.
- the cases below assumes above issues are resolved.

---

### Cases

---

**Parent node contains only empty child nodes**
In this scenario, the complexity for the worst case is `O(n)`

[image: 5 nodes]

---

**Every child node can only contain up to 1 less their parent's size**
In this scenario, the complexity for the worst case is `O(n!)`

[image: 1 tree node, 2 tree node, 3 tree node]

---

**No restrictions**
In this scenario, the complexity for the worst case is `undefined`. as the structure can contain an unrestricted amount of elements.

---

If there are any mistakes, issues, or questions. Feel free to ask!